# Remove specific user permissions from one folder in Sharepoint online with powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, csom

I am having trouble figuring out how to remove a specific user from a folder.  I have sharing the folder with the user working, but cant seem to get it to remove.... below is where i am at... any pointers?

```
$FolderToBreak = "/sitename/Documents/testtt123"
$userToRemove = "user@domain.com"

##Variables for Processing
$SiteUrl = "https://sitename.sharepoint.com/sitename"
$UserName="globaladmin@domain.com.au"
$Password ="xxxxxx"

Add-Type -Path "c:\CSOM\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "c:\CSOM\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

#Setup Credentials to connect
$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName,(ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force))

Try { 
#Set up the context
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl) 
$Context.Credentials = $credentials

#Get the List Root Folder
$Folder=$Context.web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($FolderToBreak)
#break inheritance just incase, should already be broken to share user to begin with
$Folder.ListItemAllFields.BreakRoleInheritance($true,$false)

#want to remove permission from the user $userToRemove from $folder but roleassignements doesnt have a .remove, and now i am lost....
$Folder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments....

}
catch {
    write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the PowerShell below to achieve it.

```
##Variables for Processing
$SiteUrl = "https://sitename.sharepoint.com/sitename"
$UserName="globaladmin@domain.com.au"
$Password ="xxxxxx"
$FolderToBreak = "/sitename/Documents/testtt123"
$userToRemove = "user@domain.com"

Add-Type -Path "c:\CSOM\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "c:\CSOM\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

Try { 
    #Setup Credentials to connect
    $Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName,(ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force))

    #Set up the context
    $Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl) 
    $Context.Credentials = $credentials

    #Get user
    $User = $Context.web.EnsureUser($userToRemove)
    $Context.load($User)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()

    #Get the List Root Folder
    $Folder=$Context.web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($FolderToBreak)
    #break inheritance just incase, should already be broken to share user to begin with
    $Folder.ListItemAllFields.BreakRoleInheritance($true,$false)
    #remove user permission in the folder
    $Folder.ListItemAllFields.RoleAssignments.GetByPrincipal($User).DeleteObject()
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()
}
catch {
    write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
}
```